# Android получение информации с сайта

Tags: android, запрос

Какой способ более оптимальный по скорости и интернет трафику для получения информации с сайта на мобильное приложение ? Мне в голову приходит только загружать страничку и парсить ее. Можно ли это сделать иначе ?

Comment: Сделать иначе можно всегда. Вопрос в том, что за информация и где она воспроизводится далее.

Comment: Гадание на кофейной гуще...

Comment: Парсинг html далеко не всегда самый оптимальный способ получения информации с сайтов. Есть куча других форматов и способов передачи. Выбор способа зависит от формата сайта/ресурса и даже от его контента.

Comment: ну если конкретнее, есть сайт рекламного агенства и из него мне надо в мобильное приложение получить допустим их услуги. Не знаю пока еще есть как устроен сайт и есть ль там АПИ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

от сайта зависит.

HTML не самое оптимальное в этом плане, т.к. кроме данных содержит разметку и прочее, что для парсинга лишнее и обычно выходит тяжелее, чем json.

лучше, чтобы у сайта было REST API, возвращающее json, xml, или RSS.

если сайт ваш - то можете просто допилить.
если нет - то имеем то, что имеем.
у официального API (c JSON) как правило меньше возможностей, чем у веб-морды, и авторизация не по логину и паролю, а oAuth, что не всегда удобно. но зато легче, проще и админы не ставят преград :)

Comment: Спасибо, возможно подойдет, правда не знаю пока на чем сайт устроен.

Comment: @АлексейМедведев сделайте ответ решением (галочка слева). пожалуйста, всегда рад. как работает веб-морда - рекомендую смотреть с помощью http://www.telerik.com/fiddler но вебморда как правило работает не через открытое API, даже если оно есть, поэтому есть оно или нет - можно узнать только с помощью поиска и осмотра сайта (ссылки внизу стр. "Разработчикам" и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

> ну если конкретнее, есть сайт рекламного агенства и из него мне надо в
>   мобильное приложение получить допустим их услуги. Не знаю пока еще
>   есть как устроен сайт и есть ль там АПИ

Вряд ли есть. Тогда парсите, с помощью Jsoup, например.